# Magento 2 rest api: Ignore out of stock products in get products search criteria

Tags: magento2, rest-api, out-of-stock, search-criteria

I am using the following api call to get products.

```
{{base_url}}/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=description&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=%t shirt%&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]=type_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]=configurable
```

The above call will list all configurable products with a word tshirt in its description field. And all are working fine.

The issue is it also lists the products which are in out of stock. (All the configurable variant of the product is in out of stock).

Is there any way to filter out the outofstock products? How can I specify thant in search criteria?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?